# Using android ADB to unlock a locked phone - when password contains # as first character

Tags: android, adb

My pixel 4a phone screen is totally broken. I am using ADB to try to unlock my phone. I got the following command below off the site which works, until I put # in. My password is #xxxxx

adb shell input keyevent 26 && adb shell input keyevent 82 && adb shell input text #xxxxx && adb shell input keyevent 66

It stops as soon as it hits the # which is the first character of my pwd.

Could someone please help on how to send a text starting with # to the phone?

Thanks, Vic

Comment: An USB keyboard may be the easier way to unlock your phone, assuming the phone supports USB OTG.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I hadn't thought of that and will give it a go.